# Android, How to keep a CountDownTimer running while other activity is Launched

Tags: android, multithreading

Hello I have an Activity that shows a CountDown in a textView (using CountDownTimer), but when I Launch an other activity (config screen) or change screen orientation the countDownTimer is stopped and I want keep this timer running in background, I tried to make a thread with the CountDowntimer inside, but it doesn't work, anyone Knows a way to do that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to make a background thread to have a timer running. Just remember the time when timer was started, then when you need to restart it just show the time base on this remembered time value.

So:

1. When starting a timer by user, record the system time as a start time.
2. Start the timer inside the AsyncTask and update the UI based on the recorded start time.
3. When Activity goes away, just stop the asyncTask.
4. When Activity becomes Active, restart the AsyncTask and proceed with 2.
5. When user stops the timer, reset the start time and stop the asyncTask

Comment: @Enric Please also upvote when you accept. I threw in a few upvotes for your questions. They were good.

Answer (score 1):

You can override onPause method and stop the timer then save last value there. You also need to override onResume and start your timer with last value.

Comment: But it doesn't keep the timer runnig, for instance: -start main Activity time elapsed: 0 sec timer shows 0 sec, -after 15 seconds I open the other activity (save timer value, and 5 seconds spended in the new activity) Go back to first activity: (restore timer value) time elapsed: 20 sec timer shows 15 sec.

Comment: you can also save current time inside onPause(), use System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: you can save the time when leaving first activity inside onPause(), use System.currentTimeMillis(); then use same method to get the time when go back to first activity inside onResume(). The difference should be add to your 15 secs.

Comment: Thanks I did it, but with GregorianCalendar and it works fine